# Quotient group operations

Tags: group-theory

Something on Wikipedia is confusing me, and it is the group operations performed on $\mathbb{Z_4}/\{0,2\}$.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group#Examples

What is really going on in with the addition in
$$\{ 0, 2 \} + \{ 1, 3 \} = \{ 1, 3\}$$
?

Comment: (0,2) is the identity element in the said ring..

Comment: @JDrinas, it is, but what if I have two non-identity elements?

Comment: Well, it is not "addition" in any basic, high-schooly term: the **element** $\;\{0,2\}+\{1,3\}\;$ in the quotient group $\;\Bbb Z_4/\{0,2\}\;$ is in fact just an equivalence class determined by the subgroup $\;\{0,2\}\le\Bbb Z_4\;$ . It is really messy to try to explain this from scratch in this site and perhaps you should try to reach for your teacher\instructor.

Comment: @Timbuc I have no instructor. Can you tell me articles I should read?

Comment: Nevermind I understand the operation.

Comment: @user245481 More than articles, grab a good basic group theory book. There are several very good ones, but most of them assume you've already studied some basic calculus, set theory and linear algebra at least. A good geometry background can be helpful, too.

Answer (score 3):

What's "really" going on is that when you add an even number and an odd number, you get an odd number. At least, that's how I would parse that. The coset $\{0,2\}$ is the coset of even numbers, and the coset $\{1,3\}$ is the coset of odd numbers in this case. Of course, this might be the interpretation that appeals to my inner number theorist.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, in algebra, if you add two sets as in $A + B$, the answer is the set of elements you can write as $a + b$, where $a$ comes from $A$ and $b$ comes from $B$. In your case,
\begin{align*}
\{0,2\} + \{1,3\} &= \{0+1,0+3,2+1,2+3\} \\
&= \{1,3,3,5\} \\
&= \{1,3,3,1\} \text{ (recalling } 5 = 1 \text{ in } \mathbb{Z}_4 \text{)}\\
&= \{1,3\} \text{ (recalling that duplicate elements don't matter in a set)}
\end{align*}

Comment: How would you explain to a newbie how come from your second line to third line that $\;5\;$ there disappears??

Comment: @Timbuc Good point; I edited for increased clarity.